# Small menu proplem

Tags: android, menu

I am trying to implement [this](https://github.com/honcheng/ScrollableTabHost-for-Android) "tab" style in my program, i have it working but the menu's dont work in my different activities since they dont display like normal tabs do. What i had to do to get menu's is to put it in the activity that creates the tabs but the problem comes when I hit the menu button on the phone and then hit back without selecting a menu item. The next time i hit menu it will display the last menu i was in even if i am in a different activity.

For example Activity "A" with Menu "MA" was selected then i go to Activity "B" with Menu "MB" then hit menu, the menu "MA" will show up and not "MB" which is what should show up.

this is my menu declaration

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    Log.d("onTabChanged", "selectedTab: " + String.valueOf(selectedTab));

    switch(selectedTab){
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        menu.add(1,0,0, "Item 1 ").setIcon(Main.resizeImage(this,R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences,100,100));
        menu.add(1,1,0, "Item 2").setIcon(Main.resizeImage(this, R.drawable.ic_menu_invite,100,100));
        return true;
    case 2:
        menu.add(1,2,0,"Item 3").setIcon(Main.resizeImage(this,R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences,100,100));        
        return true;
    case 3:
        menu.add(1,3,0,"Item 4").setIcon(Main.resizeImage(this,R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences,100,100));            
        menu.add(1,4,0, "Item 5").setIcon(Main.resizeImage(this, R.drawable.ic_menu_invite,100,100));
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

menu selection is based on the tab number selected.

will i not be able to do it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move menu creation to `onPrepareOptionsMenu` procedure. The `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called only once for current activity, but `onPrepareOptionsMenu` - every time just before the menu is going to be shown.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.d("onTabChanged", "selectedTab: " + String.valueOf(selectedTab));

    menu.clear();  // Do not forget to clear previous menu
    switch(selectedTab){
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        menu.add(1,0,0, "Item 1 ").setIcon(Main.resizeImage(this,R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences,100,100));
        menu.add(1,1,0, "Item 2").setIcon(Main.resizeImage(this, R.drawable.ic_menu_invite,100,100));
        return true;
    case 2:
        menu.add(1,2,0,"Item 3").setIcon(Main.resizeImage(this,R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences,100,100));        
        return true;
    case 3:
        menu.add(1,3,0,"Item 4").setIcon(Main.resizeImage(this,R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences,100,100));            
        menu.add(1,4,0, "Item 5").setIcon(Main.resizeImage(this, R.drawable.ic_menu_invite,100,100));
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: doing that just displays both the last menu and the new menu and just keeps stacking up as i move through activities

Comment: Did you see the line in my code which I specially commented? `menu.clear();  // Do not forget to clear previous menu`

Comment: ahh didnt know about the menu.clear() thanks works as intended now, most have edited as i replied